# Why does it match on part of a word but not the whole word?

Tags: elasticsearch

I have an index with documents with the name property. My target document has the following value : `"name" : "Eiker Football Team Crows"`. There are quite a few with "Eiker" somewhere in their name as it is a region. Searches for `Football Team` finds this document and so does `eik football team` or even `eike` (though it finds others too). What is really weird is that `Eiker` finds NONE of the documents with the word, but does suggest some with permutations like `Eker` or `Eikeland`. Literally searching for the full correctly spelled and cased name as the document I am looking for, does NOT find it.

This is the search I am trying to do as written in Kibana developer:

```
GET orgs/_search
{
  "query": {
    "match": {
      "name": {
        "query": "eiker",
        "operator": "and",
        "fuzziness": "auto",
        "max_expansions": 5,
        "prefix_length": 0
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Why does my Elastic search hate `r`?

I have tried different values of expansions or prefixes. Or `or` instead of `and` operator.

Comment: put index mapping in question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simple answer of your question is you are using `fuzziness` so it will do the fuzzy matching as well. Please check [this](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-match-query.html#query-dsl-match-query-fuzziness) documentation.

> fuzziness allows fuzzy matching based on the type of field being
> queried.

Also, Elasticsearch return top 10 result only by default. If you want to get more result then set `size` param value to large number.

**Update:**

As per your comment, you are using `autocomplete` as index time analyzer and  `autocomplete_search` as search time analyzer so thats why result are not coming. Try the below query with same analyzer which is use at index time for `name` field and it should return result. (Please add your index mapping and analyzer setting in question so it will easy to answer question)

```json
POST sampleindex/_search
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "must": [
        {
          "match": {
            "name": {
              "query": "Eiker",
              "operator": "and",
              "fuzziness": "auto",
              "max_expansions": 5,
              "prefix_length": 0,
              "analyzer": "autocomplete"
            }
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: fuzziness should surely add more hits, not take away actual matches? If I remove the fuzziness part from the request, I find the target with `eik`, but not with `eiker`.

Comment: i think so you are only getting top 10 result and due to higher relevancy of other document it is not coming on top.

Comment: No. I am getting empty results with `eiker` and some, including the target with `eik`.  fuzziness of 0 or auto doesn't seem relevant

Comment: what is type of name field ? is it keyword or text ?

Comment: searchable string in the index pattern

Comment: index pattern is diffrent things. can you please post index mapping in your question. you can get index mapping by  using command in kibana `GET orgs`

Comment: ```"name" : {
          "type" : "text",
          "analyzer" : "autocomplete",
          "search_analyzer" : "autocomplete_search"
        },```

Comment: please check my updated answer and hope it will helps you. my understanind is you are using diff analyzer for index and search time and thats why it is not working.

Comment: @AlexanderMorland thanks for upvoting. please mark as solution if it really helps you.

Comment: Could you add why "autocomplete_search" is not the right one for a search and why this problem manifests as it does (giving a search that works 99% of the time)?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/242811/discussion-between-sagar-patel-and-alexander-morland).